# OnLongCLickListener is not working as I need

Tags: java, android, onlongclicklistener

I have a `TextView`, with a `onLongClickListener` and `OnClick` event, on holding `TextView`, its color changes to red, and on releasing, its color is supposed to change to white.

**Problem:**
When I hold the `TextView` and move my finger outside of it while holding, and then leave my finger, its color does not change to white.

**XML**

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:text="hello"
    android:textColor="#ffff"
    android:id="@+id/timer"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
```

**Java**

```
final TextView t1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timer);
    t1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            t1.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);

        }
    });
    t1.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            t1.setTextColor(Color.RED);
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: have you tried returning true on your onLongClick()?

Comment: You should use OnTouchListener to achieve the desired functionality

Comment: @Abhishec Kumar my answer will help you to solve your issue ^_^ if you need to clear something you can ask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**`View.OnClickListener`** - Interface definition for a callback to be invoked when a view is ***clicked***.
**`View.OnLongClickListener`** - Interface definition for a callback to be invoked when a view has been ***clicked AND held***.

So what you are saying is 100% true.It should be red because its being been clicked and held as the way you did.

> But when i hold the text view and move my finger outside the text view
>   while holding , and then leave my finger , it not changes its color to
>   white

You have given color white to text view when it gets only clicked !! If you want to get that white like you said(when clicked and held), you need to set the white color in **`OnLongClickListener`**

To the point if you want to detect your views touch and release and change colors related to that then you need to use **`OnTouchListener`** instead of clickListeners

**`View.OnTouchListener`** - Interface definition for a callback to be invoked when a touch event is dispatched to this view. The callback will be invoked before the touch event is given to the view

```
       t1.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            switch ( event.getAction() ) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    t1.setTextColor(Color.RED); // pressed state
                 break;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    t1.setTextColor(Color.WHITE); // Released state
                 break;
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Comment: @Abhishec Kumar I saw you return false though this is for additional knowledge http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21578476/what-actually-happens-if-i-return-false-in-a-ontouchlistener

Answer (score 0):

Use `OnTouchListener` that way you can register touch down and up events. MotionEvent `case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:` will set the color to red when the user touches down on your `TextView`, and `case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:` will set the color to white when the user lifts their finger off the `TextView`.

```
final TextView t1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timer);


t1.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener()
    {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
        {
        switch (event.getAction()) {

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            t1.setTextColor(Color.RED);
            break; 
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            t1.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            break;
    }
return true;
        }
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

Assign a onTouch listener and look for MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN and MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
       // Construct a rect of the view's bounds
       rect = new Rect(v.getLeft(), v.getTop(), v.getRight(), v.getBottom());
    }

    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
        if (!rect.contains(v.getLeft() + (int) event.getX(), v.getTop() + (int) event.getY())) {
            // User moved outside bounds
            t1.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```