# OnTouchListener's onTouch false return value does not prevent onTouchEvent from being called. Why does everyone say it does?

Tags: android, android-layout, view, touch, touch-event

The documentaion isn't very clear about it https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener either, nor are the SO threads any help

[SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21578592/13400850):

> If you return false the event will be passed to parent views for handling.

So I tested it over and over and over again, take any view, a button, a recyclerview, anything. Now return false from its `setOnTouchListener` method. The view still behaves normally.

This means that event does not flow to its parent, it gets consumed in the same view's `onTouchEvent`. However returning true from the `onTouch`, will cause the event to be consumed right then and there! No expected behaviour from the view can be observed.

What I was trying to do:

I was trying to find out if returning false from the a view's listener's `onTouch` method actually prevents the `onTouchEvent` from being called. It doesn't. However most people online say it does.

Answer (score 0):

You're confused.  Returning true or false doesn't precent onTouchEvent from being called.  Absolutely nobody is saying that.  In fact that would be impossible-  onTouchEvent is what calls the onTouchListener.  Returning true prevent's the *parent view's* onTouchEvent from being called.  The view that contains the view being touched-  the layout it's in. Not the view itself.

Comment: I don't think i am. I tested it out with a custom view. If i consumed the event in the listener onTouchEvent does not get called. Go ahead, try it.

"Returning true also* prevents the parent view's onTouchEvent from being called."

Comment: @XiDLegend I've been using this API for 15 years.  I know what it does and how it works.  You're the one who doesn't understand it.  If the doc says it does X, and everyone on the internet says it does X, it probably does X and you see something different, you're probably the one who's wrong.