# setText() on the edittext that is focussed

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, focus, settext

I have 4 `EditText`'s now I want to put text in it on the one that is focussed and after that I want to go to the next `EditText`

anyone an idea how I can do this?

what I want:

```
focussedEditText.setText("hi");
focusOnNextEditText;
```

Comment: an Edittext has focus when its being flirted with _(i kkonw you already know that).. but i am thinking you are having 4 edittext text, which any one of which can gain focus..right?

Answer (score 0):

This might help

```
android.view.View.OnFocusChangeListener;
edittext.setOnFocusChangeListener(myEditTextFocus);
```

and `requestFocus()` too.

Answer (score 0):

```
edit_Text.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {
@Override
public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
if(hasFocus)
{
    edit_Text.setText("Your text");
    Second_edit_text.requestFocus();

 }else {

}});
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you explained what you did here.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want..

```
EditText e1,e2;
Button b1,b2;
String evalue;
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    e1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    e2=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    b1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    b2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);

    e1.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener()
    {
        public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1)
        {
            evalue="1";
            return false;
        }
    });

    e2.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener()
    {
        public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1)
        {
            evalue="2";
            return false;
        }
    });
    b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            if(evalue=="1")
            {
                e1.setText("yes");
            }
            if(evalue=="2")
            {
                e2.setText("yes");
            }
        }
    });


    b2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            if(evalue=="1")
            {
                e1.setText("No");
            }
            if(evalue=="2")
            {
                e2.setText("No");
            }
        }
    });

}
```

Am I correct... If yes then please refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17341946/how-can-i-detect-focused-edittext-in-android/17342816#17342816) answer for more detail..

Answer (score 0):

you have 4 edittext.. which implies that they are views in a viewgroup (Viewgroup is the parent view- or a view that has children- could be linear or realative or frame even viewflipper layout)? so to this

```
Viewgroup.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Viewgroup.getFocusedChild().setText("Ellt's solution works");
            return false;
        }
    });
```

correct silly errors

EDIT 1: well all you have to do is override it-(but this will only be called once for a viewgroup), it when it gets focus.. but after that it doesnt loose it..

you can always implement it your way, i dont really know how your code is constructed but you can always get the focused child by `Viewgroup.getFocusedChild()` and you can also do this

```
private void customfocuses(View v){   // the view here can be replaced with EditText directly- but for wider range i used View   
   v.setText("Ellt's solution works");
   Viewgroup.focusSearch(v,View.FOCUS_DOWN);
   v.clearFocus(); // remove if you want..just wanted to follow code structure..
   customfocuses(Viewgroup.getFocusedChild());
}
```

all this does is it sets the text to the view and also, tells the viewgroup to find a next 
view that wants focus and gives it to it and the whole scenario begins again with 
`customfocuses(Viewgroup.getFocusedChild());` also the `View.FOCUS_DOWN` specifies the
direction of the searching for focus views..

So, then you call this the first time you need it.. `customfocuses(Viewgroup.getFocusedChild());`

what the `clearFocus()` does is it removes focus from a view.. thats about it

Note: the Viewgroup in ma code are to be replaced with actually viewgroup not the class as 
i did..

let me know if i it ws good..okay, Sir? lol..

Comment: yeah this is what i want but then with an OnFocusChangeListener because you never touch the edittext :p