# Unable to hide soft keyboard after enter text in edit text

Tags: android

I have an layout with 5 Edit texts and 3 radio buttons and two button..After 5 edit texts I have 3 radio buttons and after that 2 buttons. After enter the text in fifth edit text I am unable to see radio buttons and normal buttons due to soft keyboard. How can I disable that soft keyboard after enter the fifth edit text? Can any one please help me out of this problem...

Comment: Ideally you shouldn't be doing it because it is up to the user to determine whether he is done editing.So shouldn't the user being the one closing the keyboard?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code snippet to hide/close the soft keyboard

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(
     WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN
);
```

Comment: It hides soft keyboard after enter the text in last edit tetx?  I applied InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(
        Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
  imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(country.getWindowToken(), 0); code for last edit text value

Answer (score 0):

```
public void hideKeyBord(View view) {
    if (view != null) {
        if (keyBoardHide == null) {
            keyBoardHide = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);

        }
        if (keyBoardHide != null && keyBoardHide.isActive()) {
            // to hide keyboard
            keyBoardHide.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager)
                getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);

        inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getActivity().getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(),
                InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
        getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use :

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, 0);
```

whenever you want to hide the soft keyboard.

**In your case :**
Let your fifth `EditText` be `et`..
Then use :

```
if(!et.toString().equals(null)){
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, 0);
}
```

**OR**

**You can detect if the fifth `EditText` was `focused` or not** and then acting accordingly(i.e Hiding the keyboard using the method above if the `EditText` was `focused`) by following the link below: 
[How can I detect focused EditText in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17341946/how-can-i-detect-focused-edittext-in-android)

**OR**

**Detect `Done` key event on soft keyboard :**

The keyboard would automatically close when `DONE` button is pressed. But if you want to perform customs actions when `DONE` button is pressed, refer below :

```
        et= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_text); 

        et.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() { 
            @Override 
            public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
                if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
                    // do your stuff here 
                InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, 0);
                } 
                return false; 
            } 

    });
```

Hope this Helps!

Comment: I will test 2nd one what you place here

Comment: Sure, Let me know if you get stuck somewhere!

Comment: Actually in some mobiles in soft keyboard there is a key button Done after all values entered

Comment: Yeah you can detect the key event for done key.
Follow the link below :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5077425/android-detect-done-key-press-for-onscreen-keyboard
@yamuna

Comment: I am getting confused my testing mobile had done key so after all values entered i can go with done button so it hides the soft keyboard so i have no problem with this. All mobiles will get done option?

Comment: Updated my answer .
Yeah all the edittexts will open a soft keyboard with DONE button, until and unless the EditText is single line. @yamuna

Comment: No.. I just want done button after the edit text values entered. I have that doubt only is all mobiles display done key?

Comment: Yeah they will! @yamuna

Comment: New Line button instead of done would be shown if your edittext is multiline

Answer (score 0):

Hiding keyboard is not a big question ,but u need to confirm "when ?"
you need to call

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(edittext.getApplicationWindowToken(), 0);
```

for hiding softkeyboard

try to add `android:imeOptions="actionNext"` in your edittext xml file and

```
edittext.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onEditorAction(TextView textView, int i, KeyEvent keyEvent) {
                boolean flag= false;
                if (i == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT) {
                    flag= true;
                    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(edittext.getApplicationWindowToken(), 0);
                }
                return flag;
            }
        });
```

this code will hide your soft keyboard on click next in keyboard