# Android Forms : Get focused text field id

Tags: android, android-edittext, focus

I have two Text fields. I have focus on the first text field. If I click on a button I should be able to find which text field has focus and want to know its id.

```
<EditText
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:id="@+id/editText2"
  android:layout_below="@+id/editText"
  android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
  android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
  android:layout_marginTop="33dp"
  android:hint= "@string/rfid_plh"
  android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
  android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<EditText
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:id="@+id/editText2"
  android:layout_below="@+id/editText"
  android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
  android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
  android:layout_marginTop="33dp"
  android:hint= "@string/rfid1_plh"
  android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
  android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
```

How to achieve this?

Comment: You check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17342104/3931910

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I detect focused EditText in android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17341946/how-can-i-detect-focused-edittext-in-android)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This will do it for you:

```
    final EditText et1,et2;
    Button checkButton;

    //initilize both edit text and button here

    checkButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(et1.hasFocus()){
                //TODO code here for edit text 1
                int id = et1.getId();
            }else if(et2.hasFocus()){
                //TODO code here for edit text 2
                int id = et2.getId();

            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Can you please write a little bit about the change you did here. Or something about the code?

Comment: OnClick of the button I've just checked which EditText has focus, by using the method .hasFocus(). Then to get the id of that EditText I've used the method .getId(). Its very straight forward. What is there that you are not getting? Please specify.